# Order of differencing and logging data

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I have a simple question:
Why is it not a good idea to take the log of differenced data? i.e. log(diff(Y)). 
I am told diff(log(Y)) is better.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your time series is strictly increasing, you will end up attempting to take the logarithm of negative values. The logarithm is undefined for negative values.

Comment: And so is the logarithm of zero, in case no change occurs between two time points.